# Redux form this.props.onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have three 8 checkboxes with a separate field name like Field1.....Field8
and there is one more checkbox says **globalCheck**

I want to handle 8 checkbox selection on checking this global checkbox.

Now what is happening here every time for every checkbox need to trigger `this.props.onchange` wih field name like below.

*

```
<Field  name='globalCheck' onChange={ (e) => {
    props.change('Field1', e.target.checked)
    .
    . 
    .
    props.change('Field8', e.target.checked)
}} type='checkbox' component='input'/>
```

- 

Now it's rendering component 8 times

How can I do the same behavior in one go?

Comment: Can you show your code/sandbox?

Comment: its because you are calling `props.change` 8 times. make a function that marks all the fields as checked on a single function call. something like `props.markAll`